# How do I display a particular changelist number in p4v?

Tags: perforce, p4v, changelist

When viewing submitted changelists in p4v, is there a way to display a particular changelist number?  That is, how I do the equivalent of `p4 describe` in p4v?  Can I filter for a particular changelist number?  I don't see how.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Search > Go To...
In the dialog, you can go to a submitted changelist by number.

In my version of P4, this is under Edit > Go To...

Answer (score 41):

And of course for the keyboard freaks ("mouse? I don't need no mouse") you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

Hi All,
                                                                                                                                                                                                       It I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and then I was prmopted to provide the change list number.

Please note you have to select the options from Scroll down Menu.

In this case it is:

1. Submitted Change List
2. Pending change list
3. Branch Mapping
4. Label
5. Workspace
6. User
7. Job

Answer (score 2):

Like Eric, I use Edit > Go To...

Optionally, in the History pane on the left side of the window, you can double click on a changelist in the list and it'll open the details for just that changelist in a new window (same window you'll see with Edit > Go To...).

Answer (score 2):

Note for this, in the newest version of P4V, the "Pending" and "Submitted" change types are combined in the goto dialog. Now there is just "Changelist" and it figures out which one it is by the number you enter.

Answer (score 0):

Also we can view @ tab "Search" -> Go To.. in newer versions of P4V. AS mentioned above or     "Ctlr+G "